# Finding the limit of a shifted function?

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose I have some function $f(x)$ and some other function $g(x) = f(x-c)$.

Is is true that if $\lim_{x\to -c}f(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ exists and

$$\lim_{x\to -c}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$$

?

It seems to make intuitive sense to me, as shifting a function doesn't seem like it should change the limit as long as we shift the value $x$ is approaching accordingly.

Comment: It's a simple substitution $x=t-c$ and $t\to 0$.

Comment: since the limit exists, it is weakly continuous (it has removable discontinuities) can be extended to have continuous conditions. Composition of continuous functions is continuous therefore limit exists.

Comment: @rldias: if $x\to c$ then we need to use $x=t+c$ and the limit is then equal to $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x+c) $ and we must then define $g(x) =f(x+c) $ for the result to be valid.

Comment: Also note that such a substitution is two way (invertible) $x=t-c, t=x+c$ so that the limits $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to - c} f(x) $ are equivalent. If one fails to exist then another also fails to exist in the same manner.